# Uncaught ReferenceError in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm working on a tiny project for learning React and I got stuck.

**My problem:** When a post request called, I get: "Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined". Someone can figure out why??

In addition, I want the ul to re-render every new post created.
If I changed this:

```
handleSend(msg){
        this.state.val.push(msg);
        this.setState({val});
    }
```

to this:

```
handleSend(msg){
        this.state.val.push(msg);
        this.setState({val: []});
    }
```

I don't get any errors but i need to refresh the page to see the new post on the ul.

**This is my code:**
Hope you guys can figure it out and help me :)

```
  class CoachPage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state={
      val: []
    };
  }

  handleSend(msg){
    this.state.val.push(msg);
    this.setState({val});
}

componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/')
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => this.setState({ val: data }))
    .catch( console.error ); 
}

 deleteMsg(id){
    return fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/msgs/' + id, {
      method: 'DELETE'
    })
      .then(response =>
        response.json()
      .then(json => {
        return json;
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container"  style={{color: '#FFF', textAlign: 'right'}}>
        <h1>Coach Page</h1>
        <AddMsg onSend={this.handleSend.bind(this)}/>
        <Panel header="עדכונים" bsStyle="info" style={{float: 'left', textAlign: 'right', width: '40em'}}>
        <ul id="coach-panel-content">
        { 
          this.state.val.map( (msg, index) =>
            <li dir="rtl" key={index} className='myli'>
              {msg.msgdata}
              <span onClick={() => this.deleteMsg(msg._id)}>X</span>
              <hr/>
            </li>
          )
        }
        </ul>
        </Panel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CoachPage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

You had some problems:

- `val` was `undefined` because you never assigned a value to it
- `msg` is a `String` not an `Object`. In your render method you access to an `Object` `{msg.msgdata}`

---

`val` is undefined because you don't assign any value to it.

`{ val; } // not defined` vs `{ val : "Message" } //defined`

```
handleSend(msg){
 this.setState(prevState => ({val: [...prevState.val, { msgdata: msg }] }));
}
```

I think you misunderstood the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: even better `this.setState({ val:  this.state.val.concat([msg])});`

Comment: even better ? `this.setState({ val : [...this.state.val, msg] });`

Comment: OK. Now i don't get the error and it looks like the ul re-render but not good. I cant see the text. Only after refreshing the page i can see it properly..

Comment: can you log your data, before the setState call? `const val = this.state.val.concat([msg]); console.log(val)`

Comment: yes. it gives me: val is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],my val

Comment: Can you log just the msg? I think you have a problem in `<AddMsg onSend={this.handleSend.bind(this)}/>`

Comment: When i log the msg i get the text that i want to post.

Comment: I updated my anwser. Ok you need to create an Object with you `msg` like this: `{ msgdata : msg }` so `this.setState({ val : [...this.state.val, { msgdata : msg }] });`

Comment: WORK PERFECT!! Please edit your answer so i can mark it as the proper answer. Also It will be helpful for me if you can explain your answer.

Comment: @Li357 This was not the problem. Please check the React docs, they do not "always" merge the state in their examples. I think my response was useful so why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees about when setState gets executed, so you are better using the version of setState that takes an update function; the first parameter of which is your current (up to date) state:

```
handleSend(msg) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return {val: [...prevState.val, msg]};
    });
}
```

Comment: It is also works but the problem is now in render i think. i can see the span and the hr added but not the text. Only after refresh the page i can see the li properly

Comment: is the ```msg``` parameter undefined?

Comment: When i log the msg i get the text that i want to post

Comment: Does msg look like: ```{ id: 'foo', msgdata: 'bar' }``` ?